# How to hide & disable Expand/Collapse button of JqGrid GroupingView

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am new to JqGrid,
I am using GroupingView functionality of JqGrid.
It shows Collapse/Expand button with each group & on click of it it hides/shows the grouped items inside it.
I want to hide & disable the Collapse/Expand button.
Please find the JsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/564RP/25/

Please help me. Thanks in advance...

```
enter code here
```

Comment: do you want to hide or disable Collapse/Expand button, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide collapse / expand button by adding below script at the bottom of document.ready function :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
... your code ..

...............

$('.tree-wrap-ltr').hide();

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/564RP/26/)**